# Buffer Overflow error on custom STRAGG function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, overflow, aggregation, truncate

I am using a custom STRAGG, which truncates string at 4000, as following,

> select STRAGG('000 - ' || CHANGE_TEXT) from TBL_CHANGE_SUMMARY

this works fine in development oracle server, however it gets following error in production environment.

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Following is the custom code that had modified STRAGG,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "STRING_AGG_TYPE" as object
(
  total varchar2(4000),
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self  IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                       value IN varchar2) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self        IN string_agg_type,
                                         returnValue OUT varchar2,
                                         flags       IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                     ctx2 IN string_agg_type) return number
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY "STRING_AGG_TYPE" is

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type ) return number is
  begin
    sctx := string_agg_type(null);

    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self  IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                       value IN varchar2) return number is
   BEGIN
      --prevent buffer overflow for more than 4,000 characters
     IF NVL(LENGTH(self.total), 0) + NVL(LENGTH(VALUE), 0) < 3930 THEN
        IF (self.total IS NULL) THEN
           self.total := VALUE;
        ELSIF INSTR ('~#~' || self.total || '~#~', '~#~' || VALUE || '~#~',1,1) = 0 AND INSTR ( self.total, '[TRUNCATED]',1,1) = 0 THEN
                self.total := self.total || '~#~' || VALUE;
        END IF;
     ELSE
        IF INSTR ( self.total, '[TRUNCATED]',1,1) = 0 THEN
            self.total := self.total || '[TRUNCATED]';
        END IF;
     END IF;

      RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
   END;


   MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate (self          IN     string_agg_type,
                                           returnValue      OUT VARCHAR2,
                                           flags         IN     NUMBER)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF INSTR ( self.total, '[TRUNCATED]',1,1) = 0 THEN
         returnValue := LTRIM (self.total, '~#~');
      ELSE
         IF (self.total IS NOT NULL) THEN

            returnValue := SUBSTR(self.total, 1, INSTR ( self.total, '[TRUNCATED]',1,1) - 1) || '..... Truncated because of system limitation';
         END IF;
      END IF;

      RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
   END;


  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                     ctx2 IN string_agg_type) return number is
  begin
    self.total := self.total || ctx2.total;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;


end;
```

Why would same code behave differently? Is there anything I need to change or setup in Oracle environment?

Following is the difference in its usage of character in each environment,

```
Character set in Production,
NLS_CHARACTERSET          AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET    UTF8
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS      BYTE

Character set in Development,
NLS_CHARACTERSET        AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
```

Comment: Well, what line is the error on?  You must have different data in prod, no?

Comment: What characterset are you using ? Could you run this query: `select * from nls_database_parameters
where parameter like '%SEMA%'
  or parameter like '%SET';` and append it's result to the question ?

Comment: Line of error would not be in STRING_AGG_TYPE, but would be in actual sql, which is same line as my first example "select STRAGG('000 - ' || CHANGE_TEXT) from...".
And yes, it is different data in production, however I don't think its't the  data, as I explored many scenario of data size and it always works in development environment.

Comment: Thank you, chacterset info has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using AL32UTF8 - in UTF-8 some characters are encoded using 1 byte while others occupy 2 bytes or sometimes 4 bytes.
You are also using NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = BYTE (which is a default setting). 
This means that a declaration like `VARCHAR2(5)` restricts a lenght of a string 
to a maximum of **5 bytes**, **not 5 characters**.
Use `VARCHAR2( 4000 char )`, not simple `VARCHAR2( 4000 )` 
 
Please see an example how it works:

```
select * 
from nls_database_parameters
where parameter like '%SEMA%'
  or parameter like '%SET';
PARAMETER                 VALUE              
------------------------- --------------------
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS      BYTE                
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET    UTF8                
NLS_CHARACTERSET          AL32UTF8
```

and now:

```
declare
   x varchar2(10);
begin
   x := 'ąśćz123456';
   dbms_output.put_line( x );
end;
/
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: błąd liczby lub wartości: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: przy linia 4
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

but:

```
declare
   x varchar2(10 char);
begin
   x := 'ąśćz123456';
   dbms_output.put_line( x );
end;
/

ąśćz123456

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation! One quick question though, so the successful example at the bottom is using AL16UTF16? And if so, Should NLS_CHARACTERSET match with NLS_NCHAR_CHRACTERSET?

Comment: In short:`VARCHAR2` use `NLS_CHARACTERSE` and `NVARCHAR2` use  `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`. This is a huge topic, please refer to the documentation for detailed explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG002